# SyntaxHighlighter and Blogger preview mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, blogger, syntaxhighlighter

Is it possible to set up SyntaxHighlighter in the way that I can see formatting in the preview mode?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not there as of date.

Go to the official blogger product forums and post your suggestion in the suggestions forum. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/blogger/feature-suggestions--feedback

They do go through our suggestion and respond/implement our suggestions sooner or later.